# Null Pointer dereference issue never thrown in sonar

Tags: java, sonarqube, findbugs

I've been testing both the rules "Correctness - Possible null pointer dereference" and "Correctness - Possible null pointer dereference in method on exception path" 
on my sonar instance.
Unfortunately, the following code is never detected as wrong

```
 public ResultatsDTO getContent(String userName, String roid) {
    ResultatsDTO resultats = null;
    try {

        resultats = GetDocContentCaller.instance().getDocumentContent(
                userName, roid);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(
                "Erreur dans l'appel de l'ejb lors du telechargement du document docBaseId"
                        + roid, e);
        if (resultats.getErrorCode() == 0) {
            resultats.setErrorCode(ERROR_CODE_104);
            resultats.setMessage("erreur lors de l appel du web service");
        }
    }
    return resultats;
}
```

Netbeans detects correctly this issue but sonar 3.6.1 doesn't.

Is it normal ?  Is it the good rule ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: This code isn't even valid to *compile* - `test` isn't definitely assigned.

Comment: @JonSkeet Why it shouldn't compile? What has definite assignment to do with it? May be I'm missing something?

Comment: My code was wrong. I updated that.

Comment: The previous one with empty try block compiled fine for me... Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @Thihara. It would compile with empty try-block. But not, when you assign something to `test` in the `try` block. But now the code is completely changed.

Comment: Ah yes, I was referring to the original snippet.

Comment: I forgot to initialize the string

Answer (score 0):

`Sonar` is a code review tool not a compiling tool.This is a `compiling error` it will detect by `compiler`.

Comment: Yes the code snippet was wrong. I prefered to update the question